# Styling HTML Spinners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to change size, background, border etc. for spin buttons of an `input[type=number]` element.

It should be compatible with popular browsers. How can I do it with `css/jquery`.

```
<input id="painLevel" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="10" />
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you'll need to replace/hide the element and place it with elements that you can style independently if you want consistency, the default up down buttons are browser specific elements. If you really want to play with the defaults though you can probably try something like the comment in this tutorial, however they are targeting webkit only browsers http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/

Comment: oh, okey I got it. I can use seperate buttons as spinners. Thanks.